# How to fix Could not find interpolator-1.0.0.jar in Android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my application I want build APK, but after some times show me below **error** :

```
Execution failed for task ':codecanyon:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':codecanyon:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find interpolator-1.0.0.jar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/interpolator/interpolator/1.0.0/interpolator-1.0.0.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**When click on this URL :** https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/interpolator/interpolator/1.0.0/interpolator-1.0.0.jar
open URL but show me 404 error !

**My dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.00'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0'

    // loader
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to find `androidx.interpolator:interpolator` string in your project and show us those dependencies

Comment: @shmakova , I try for find this `androidx.interpolator:interpolator` with double shift search, but not found

Comment: Try with Edit > Find > Find in Path (or shortcut cmd+shift+f)

Comment: @shmakova , I checked this. not found in my project! Maybe use other library ! :(

Comment: Your dependencies work fine in my new project. Try to clean your project. Show `repositories` object from `build.gradle`

Comment: @shmakova , more than 100 times I clean project and rebuild again :D but again not work!